# Dplyr summarise multiple columns based on condition

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a datasaet like this:

```
df.in <-structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 2, 3), x1 = c(0, 1, NA, 0), x2 = c("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", 
                                                                    "dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur", "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis", 
                                                                    "Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem"), x3 = c("Donec ullamcorper elit quis risus", 
                                                                                                          "Donec ullamcorper elit quis risus", "Curabitur euismod", "Mauris felis orci"
                                                                    )), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                                    ))

> df.in
# A tibble: 4 x 4
     id    x1 x2                              x3                               
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                           <chr>                            
1     1     0 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet      Donec ullamcorper elit quis risus
2     1     1 dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur Donec ullamcorper elit quis risus
3     2    NA Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis  Curabitur euismod                
4     3     0 Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem      Mauris felis orci
```

I'm trying to `dplyr::group_by()` to obtain this:

```
df.out <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3), x1 = c(1, NA, 0), x2 = c("dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur", 
                                                                   "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis", "Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem"
), x3 = c("Donec ullamcorper elit quis risus", "Curabitur euismod", 
          "Mauris felis orci")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                   "tbl", "data.frame"))

> df.out
# A tibble: 3 x 4
     id    x1 x2                              x3                               
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                           <chr>                            
1     1     1 dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur Donec ullamcorper elit quis risus
2     2    NA Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis  Curabitur euismod                
3     3     0 Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem      Mauris felis orci
```

I can do:

```
df.in %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(x1 = max(x1))
```

However, how do I:

1. Summarize `x2`, `x3` to keep the value where `max(x1)` occurs?
2. I have several `x`'s all needing the same logic. Is there a way to do a `summarize_all`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a condition with `max` in `summarise_at`

```
library(dplyr)
df.in %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise_at(3:4, funs(if(n() == 1) . else .[x1 == max(x1, na.rm = TRUE)]))
```

---

Instead of using `summarise_at`, we can do a `filter` or `slice` as well

```
df.in %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter((n() == 1) | (x1 == max(x1, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Or use `slice`

```
df.in %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  slice(which(n() == 1 | (x1 == max(x1, na.rm = TRUE)))[1])
```

Comment: in the 2nd option, what would happen if x1 has ties?

Comment: @ThomasSpeidel  It will get all the rows that have ties.  What do you want to happen for those cases

Comment: Thx. I want to keep the first non-empty string